# JAR работает на машине, где разработан, и не работает на другой

Tags: java, javafx

Не запускается .jar на других компах. На компьютере который собрал jar запускается без проблем. Помогите пожалуйста, подскажите что делать.
Вот лог.
Весь не влазит, вот ссылка на весь https://github.com/Dugayoyo/Mar/blob/master/README.md

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class market.MainApp
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/849460928.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)   
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$158(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1711163554.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1645995473.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1925710199.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/355629945.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/410424423.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: А вы пробовали читать свои трейсы? Там вроде как все написано, в чем дело. Если непонятен конкретный exception, спрашивайте конкретно про него - с кодом, который к нему приводит.

Comment: Мне просто не совсем понятно почему на одном ошибок нет, на других есть . Ну и первое что не ясно java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Ну ОК, попробовал расшифровать вам ваш трейс. В будущем, пожалуйста, хотя бы форматируйте его. Почему на одной машине не работает. а на другой работает - может быть миллион причин - не зная ничего про ваш код, угадывать нет смысла. Хотя по трейсу видно куда копать: в настройки подключения к БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvocationTargetException` - это вид Exception'а который порождается когда падает что-то, вызванное через [Java reflection](http://www.quizful.net/post/java-reflection-api). Вы используете `javafx`, который внутри использует reflection.

[InvocationTargetException является оберткой](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020758/1026) вокруг настоящего exception'а. В стектрейсе это видно по словам "Caused by", у вас:

```
Unable to construct Application instance: class market.MainApp
```

Следуя дальше по "caused by" видна вся история:

- `Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at market.hibb.HibbUtil.(HibbUtil.java:24) at market.MainApp.(MainApp.java:52)` - вы вызвали HibbUtil, который
- `Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException` - не смог инициировать JDBC-подключение
- `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` - потому что вы неверно указали параметры подключения (по указанному connection string'у происходит connection refused)

Comment: Спасибо, как оказалось на другом компьютере был другой пароль